# Nodejs view guess multiple extensions

Tags: node.js, express, pug, ejs

I have Jade set as my primary view engine but also have some pages in ejs

How can I make it such that when I call `res.render('view')` it guesses both `view.jade` as well as `view.ejs` (and uses the appropriate engine)?

Right now I am getting an error when I specify an EJS page

```
failed to located view "viewname", tried:
/views/viewname.jade
/views/viewname/index.jade
/views/../viewname/index.jade
```

What part of node defines what views are tried? Connect/Express? The view engines themselves?
Is there anything I can do with app.register or similar?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way that I know of to make express try alternative extensions for views. But so what? If you know that "view" really means "view.ejs", just write `res.render('view.ejs')` and express will be very happy to comply with your wishes. As a developer, you can be expected to know what template engine your views are written for. If you're part of a team that's so fragmented that front-end developers and back-end developers don't talk to each other enough that either knows what the other is using to write templates, you're dealing with an organizational problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: Yes, I am fully aware that I can do 'view.ejs' as that is what I have been doing. I am mostly just curious as to whether this is possible.

Comment: This answer isn't a suitable solution and doesn't help with this question. This should have been submitted as a comment instead of an answer since it's more of an opinion than a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you can specify which engine to use, but it is possible to have your Node Express server choose from multiple extensions (based on what you tell it).

[passing extensions and other options to `express.static`](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.built-in)

**A simple Express server example:**

```
var express = require('express'),
    port = 3000,
    app = express()
;

app.use('/views/', express.static('views', {extensions: ['jade', 'ejs']}));

app.listen(port, function(error) {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } else {
        console.info('==>   Listening on port %s. Open up http://localhost:%s/ in your browser.', port, port);
    };
});
```